# How can I code a multiple input- 1 output for Neural Networks using the scikit-learn module in PYTHON?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am building a Python code that uses the scikit-learn module for two inputs (Cooling temperature and inlet flowrate) and 1 output (outlet temperature). For every input of the cooling temperature and inlet flowrate, there is one output.

I already got the data for the training step, but I am unable to actually code/combine the inputs into one input to actually fit the data.

Any suggestions?

Below is the python code I started with; it is not complete; it is giving an error.

```py
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1= np.array([[300.0], [300.0], [250.0], [250.0],[250.0],[250.0],[270.61032473]])

x2=np.array([[50],[50.5],[51],[52],[53],[53.5],[54]])

x=np.concatenate((x1,x2))

#y represents the Temperature of CSTR

y=np.array([[324.47544343, 324.47544343, 314.72646578, 306.78141638,
       300.63135097, 295.9767374 , 296.23219938]])

y=y.ravel()

nn = MLPRegressor(
    hidden_layer_sizes=(5,5,5,5),  activation='relu', solver='adam',random_state=1,max_iter=10000)

n = nn.fit(x, y)

#test_y = nn.predict([[260.0],[272.0]])

#print(test_y)
```

Below is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\t.py", line 57, in <module>
    n = nn.fit(x, y)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py", line 618, in fit
    return self._fit(X, y, incremental=False)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py", line 324, in _fit
    X, y = self._validate_input(X, y, incremental)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neural_network\multilayer_perceptron.py", line 1314, in _validate_input
    multi_output=True, y_numeric=True)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 766, in check_X_y
    check_consistent_length(X, y)
  File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 235, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [14, 7]
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: "it is giving an error" - please post the full error message

Comment: I edited the post and added the error that is shown. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x.shape == (14, 1)`, so you're passing in 14 data points and trying to correlate them with 7 data points in `y`, which won't work because the number of points in `x` and `y` must be the same.

Did you mean:

```
>>> np.hstack((x1, x2))
array([[300.        ,  50.        ],
       [300.        ,  50.5       ],
       [250.        ,  51.        ],
       [250.        ,  52.        ],
       [250.        ,  53.        ],
       [250.        ,  53.5       ],
       [270.61032473,  54.        ]])
```

Currently, your `x` looks like this:

```
>>> x
array([[300.        ],
       [300.        ],
       [250.        ],
       [250.        ],
       [250.        ],
       [250.        ],
       [270.61032473],
       [ 50.        ],
       [ 50.5       ],
       [ 51.        ],
       [ 52.        ],
       [ 53.        ],
       [ 53.5       ],
       [ 54.        ]])
```

Is this what you meant?

Comment: For every one cooling temperature and one inlet flow rates, there is one output. In my simple example, there is 7 Tc's (x1), 7 q's (x2) and 7 T's (y). For instance, at Tc=300 and q=50: T=324.47

Comment: Yes, but `np.concatenate((x1,x2))` combines `x1` and `x2` into 14 Tc's (or q's)

Comment: Yes I am aware that this step might be wrong.. That is why I asked for help my friend.. I am not sure on how to code it ..

Comment: Did you read my answer? Have you tried `x=np.hstack((x1, x2))`?

Comment: I tried it now, it worked fine. Thank you very much my friend.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1= np.array([[300.0], [300.0], [250.0], [250.0],[250.0],[250.0],[270.61032473]])

x2=np.array([[50],[50.5],[51],[52],[53],[53.5],[54]])

#Added "axis=1" to concanate two columns
x=np.concatenate((x1,x2), axis=1)
print(x)
print(x.shape)

y=np.array([324.47544343, 324.47544343, 314.72646578, 306.78141638,
       300.63135097, 295.9767374 , 296.23219938])

y=y.ravel()

nn = MLPRegressor(
    hidden_layer_sizes=(5,5,5,5),  activation='relu', solver='adam',random_state=1,max_iter=10000)

n = nn.fit(x, y)

# Modified input to be a (2,1) array
test_y = nn.predict(np.array([[260.0,272.0]]))

print(test_y)
```